# CSS selectors for two different div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to style a div if a other div contains a specific class?!
I know this can be done with jQuery but I was wondering if it can be done with CSS aswell.

Let's say I have

```
<div class="stickyWrap sticky"></div>
<div class="checkout "></div>
```

Is it possible to style `checkout` when `stickWrap` contains the class `sticky`?

I tried something like:

```
.stickyWrap[class*="sticky"] + .checkout{
  background-color: #1f6053; 
}
```

That obvious doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just chain the classnames in the selector.

```css
.stickyWrap.sticky + .checkout {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="stickyWrap">not sticky</div>
<div class="checkout ">checkout</div>

<div class="stickyWrap sticky">sticky</div>
<div class="checkout ">checkout</div>
```

Note: I think the selector you actually wanted was:

```
.stickyWrap[class$="sticky"] + .checkout{
  background-color: #1f6053; 
}
```

This will find parent elements that have both `.stickyWrap` **and** classes that *end* in "sticky"...otherwise it's too broad.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jvf33Lhq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to treat the class as an attribute; you can just select it as, well, a class! Like so:

```
.stickyWrap.sticky + .checkout{
  background-color: #1f6053; 
}
```

Comment: `other div contains a specific class` what if the classes are like `class="stickyWrap stickybomb"`

Comment: I don't understand how that's different. Just use the selector `.stickyWrap.stickybomb + .checkout`. You can chain classes for the same element as much as you want.

Comment: I think the OP's case is like he want to select elements which contains the word sticky in the second class. not the exact word. Am i right?

Comment: Ah, you might be right. If that's the case, I'd recommend OP change how their classes are added, as that approach is kind of contrary to how CSS classes are best utilized. Every time they add a class that contains the word "sticky", they could also add the class "sticky" itself.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have tagged jquery,so give this a go.

```
if($(".stickyWrap").hasClass("sticky"))
{
   $(".checkout ").css("background-color","#1f6053");
}
```

Comment: Downvoter care to comment whats the problem in this?? OP?

Comment: OP wants to know if it can be done using CSS only. I think that's why you got downvoted.

Comment: OP asked for a CSS solution, not a jQuery solution: "I know this can be done with jQuery but I was wondering if it can be done with CSS aswell."